# Include Key value in JsonSchema Validation Errors

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, json-schema-validator

I have a json file and a created a jsonSchema. And now I did the validation. It works fine.
in the error message it shows error like this:

```
['id', 4180, 'name', 'amount']
2.0 is greater than the maximum of 1
```

I want to print the Id number aswell for which the error occurs so that can track the errors in JSON file easily.

I tried the below code:

```
jsondata = json.loads(jsonInput.read())

jsonschema = json.loads(schemaInput.read())

validator = jsonschema.Draft7Validator(jsonschema )

errors = sorted(validator.iter_errors(jsondata ),key=str)  # get all validation errors

error_count=1;   
for error in errors:
    print(error)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to further inspect the errors that you are getting.

Here is an example from [the documentation](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors/#jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError):

```
for error in errors:
    for suberror in sorted(error.context, key=lambda e: e.schema_path):
        print(list(suberror.schema_path), suberror.message, sep=", ")
```

Comment: it gives me empty list. Could you please let me know why?

Comment: How would I know? You don't provide your schema, you don't provide your input, you don't provide full code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example